# Нет доступа к методу из JavaScript: ScriptException: TypeError: note.getTitle is not a function

Tags: java

Нашёл пример для работы с скриптами в *Java* [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/). Создал свой класс `Note`, создал экземпляр, положил его в `engine`, запускаю его метод `getTitle` и получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError:
note.getTitle is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
```

Сделал всё аналогично примеру по ссылке. В чём может быть проблема?

С `File` код работает, а вот с моим классом `Note` — нет.

Если писать так: `engine.eval("print(note.title)");`, то в выводе будет `undefined`.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import java.io.File;

public class Arrays {

    class Note {
        public String title, text;
        Note(String title, String text) {
            this.title = title;
            this.text = text;
        }
        public String getTitle() { return title; }
    }

    void run() throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        Note note = new Note("title", "text");
        engine.put("note", note);
        engine.eval("print(note.getTitle())");

        File f = new File("a.txt");
        engine.put("f", f);
        engine.eval("print(f.getAbsolutePath())");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Arrays main = new Arrays();
        main.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `Note` должен быть `public` чтобы движок JavaScript мог обратиться к его методам.

```
public class Note {
```